# MKPolyline isn't drawing on the map. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpolyline

I am trying to draw an `MKPolyline` on a map. When I do a simulated run on the app, the location moves correctly but no line is drawn. How can I resolve this issue?

```
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: 0)!
    mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode(rawValue: 2)!
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: 0)!
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

// MARK: - CLLocationManager delegate

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
    //drawing path or route covered
    if let oldLocationNew = oldLocation as CLLocation?{
        let oldCoordinates = oldLocationNew.coordinate
        let newCoordinates = newLocation.coordinate
        var area = [oldCoordinates, newCoordinates]
        var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &area, count: area.count)
        mapView.add(polyline)
    }

    //calculation for location selection for pointing annoation
    if let previousLocationNew = previousLocation as CLLocation?{
        //case if previous location exists
        if previousLocation.distance(from: newLocation) > 200 {
            addAnnotationsOnMap(locationToPoint: newLocation)
            previousLocation = newLocation
        }
    }
    else{
        //case if previous location doesn't exists
        addAnnotationsOnMap(locationToPoint: newLocation)
        previousLocation = newLocation
    }
}

// MARK: - MKMapView delegate

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {

    if (overlay is MKPolyline) {
        var pr = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        pr.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        pr.lineWidth = 5
        return pr
    }

    return nil
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if startDate == nil {
        startDate = Date()
    } else {
        print("elapsedTime:", String(format: "%.0fs", Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)))
        timeLabel.text="\(Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate))"
    }
    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = locations.first
    } else if let location = locations.last {
        traveledDistance += lastLocation.distance(from: location)
        print("Traveled Distance:",  traveledDistance)
        distanceLabel.text="\(traveledDistance)"
        print("Straight Distance:", startLocation.distance(from: locations.last!))
    }
    lastLocation = locations.last
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    if (error as? CLError)?.code == .denied {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        manager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
}
```

`MKPolyline` should be drawn as the user moves.

Comment: Unrelated and out of curiosity, why are you doing `mapView.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: 0)!` instead of `mapView.mapType = .standard`? And why are you doing that in `didReceiveWarning`? And why use `rawValue` for tracking mode instead of `mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading`? Also, in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`, don’t forget to call the `super` rendition. Generally when you `override` a method, you call the `super` implementation unless there are very specific reasons why you don’t want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for [`mapView(_:rendererFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452203-mapview) is incorrect. It has changed. It is now:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    switch overlay {
    case let polyline as MKPolyline:
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
        renderer.strokeColor = .red
        renderer.lineWidth = 5
        return renderer

    // you can add more `case`s for other overlay types as needed

    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected MKOverlay type")
    }
}
```

If you add a `print` statement or breakpoint inside your current method, I believe you will find that it’s not being called. And, of course, make sure that you’ve set the `delegate` of your map view, either in IB or programmatically.

---

By the way, the old [`locationManager(_:didUpdateTo:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423716-locationmanager) is deprecated. Use [`locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager) instead. You’ll have to maintain your own reference to the `savedLocation` and the `savedPolyline`:

```
var savedLocation: CLLocation?
var savedPolyline: MKPolyline?

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last(where: { $0.horizontalAccuracy >= 0 }) else { return }

    var polyline: MKPolyline?

    if let oldCoordinate = savedLocation?.coordinate {
        let coordinates = [oldCoordinate, location.coordinate]
        polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
        mapView.addOverlay(polyline!)
    }

    // if you want to remove the old one
    // 
    // if let savedPolyline = savedPolyline {
    //     mapView.removeOverlay(savedPolyline)
    // }
    // 
    // savedPolyline = polyline

    savedLocation = location

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Rob, I implemented your code but the line still isn't being drawn. I have placed my mapview.delegate in the viewdidload() method. Do I need to move that or is the issue something else?

Comment: @JasonSingh - I just tested this and it renders a polyline fine. Did you add a breakpoint or print statement to make sure it’s getting to this routine? Are you sure you’re hitting your `mapView.add(polyline)` line? Add a breakpoint there, too. (That’s a weird line, because it should be `mapView.addOverlay(polyline)`.) Basically, use the debugger or `print` statements to determine whether it’s getting to the lines of code you think it is.

Comment: Rob, I did a bit more research and I think the problem is that I have 2 locationmanager methods (I added the second instance of this method above). Do you think this is what is preventing the mkline from being drawn? Is there any way I can combine the 2 methods.

Comment: Yes. Well that first one has an incorrect method signature, too, (see my edit), and it’s deprecated anyway. Yes, you absolutely should combine them together.

Comment: Hi @Rob, this site is bIocked my asking question option. I have already draw polyline within 2 locations I want to remove polyline when the user location changed to destination. Your answer is about adding polyline with every move. How can I remove polyline while user moving.

Comment: Just save reference to the old polyline and remove it. See revised code snippet.